# How to reference a secondary project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have project A, a C# console application which I want to reference my project B, a C# class library. My goal is to be able to make use of objects in Project B from within Project A, and see the source tree for both projects in the same Solution Explorer. I can of course make a reference from Project A to the built .dll that Project B outputs and use the objects in that fashion, but this doesn't give me the control I would like.

I'm having difficulty achieving this. I assume it should be found in Add Reference -> 'Project' tab, but I don't see any items in that tab window and can't figure out how to populate it. Am I missing something here? Both projects target .NET 4.0 framework and I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 C# Express with ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to create a circular reference?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, as long as all those projects in the same solution, you should be able to add them as project reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Project A, File > Add > Existing Project

Both projects need to be in the same solution.

Comment: Wrong; this does belong here.

Comment: Thank you @SLaks, always helpful for me to re-read the faq.  As for the question, there's no mention that the OP has both projects in the same solution.

Comment: Thanks, didn't understand the relationship between projects and solutions.

Answer (score 12):

1. Open Project A
2. File - Add - Existing Project
3. Open the .csproj file for Project B

You should now be able to see the source for both projects as part of the same solution.

Now from Project A:

1. Add Reference
2. Go to Projects tab
3. Select Project B

Project A will now be able to use the types declared in Project B.